# Estou a receber registos falsos no site

Tags: php, joomla

Já há algum tempo tenho recebido registos no meu site, registos falsos e não consigo perceber o que pode estar na causa do mesmo.

Tenho um registo simples, campos, dropdowns e um pequeno captcha com imagem em MIME. O captcha tive que implementar há pouco por causa dos registos.

Descobri há pouco que os registos não estão a ser feitos diretamente pelo site, já que o captcha não teve qualquer tipo de efeito.

Será que há formas de enviar dados para uma BD sem ser pelo próprio site?

Comment: O captcha serve justamente para evitar que isso ocorra. Talvez não esteja funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Outro recurso que você pode usar para reforçar a segurança é enviar um link de validação pro email do usuário. Ou seja, enquanto o usuário não validar o link, o registro fica "morto". Assim você consegue ter mais controle sobre registros "bons" e "ruins", podendo apagar os "ruins" depois de alguns dias, para não inchar seu BD.

Comment: @dvd Tenho a certeza que o Captcha funciona. Testes múltiplas vezes, de todas as formas que me chegaram a cabeça, não detetei falhas. Sobre o link de confirmação, é uma boa ideia, mas não vai de acordo ao que estou a procura. Eu estou a procura de terminar com o spam, não filtrar. A teoria mais certeira que tenho agora, é que os registos não estão a ocorrer no site. Estão a ocorrer por uma falha de segurança do joomla.